# Probability of flipping 12 coins 5 times all being heads

Tags: probability

If I had to flip 12 coins simultaneously, and did this 5 times in a row, what are the chances that all 60 coins got heads?

Comment: There is no essential difference between throwing simultaneously or in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability is the same as if you just flipped a fair coin 60 times in a row, i.e., one in $2^{60} \approx 1.1529215 \times 10^{18} \approx 1.15$ quintillion.  The fact that you're dividing them into five batches of twelve does not affect the probability.

For comparison, the probability of winning the Powerball jackpot (a US lottery) is one in 292 million.  You are more than ten times more likely<sup>1</sup> to win the Powerball jackpot twice in a row than you are to have a coin come up heads 60 times in a row.

---

<sup>1</sup> To be precise:  $2^{60}/(292201338)^2 \approx 13.5$ times.